# I would like to simulate a simple game using conditional probability in R or Python

Tags: python, r

Imagine I have 2 teams of 2 players. For each player, there exist two probability statistics-- call one an attempt % and another a score %.

To calculate the odds of a player scoring, I would multiply the attempt % by the scoring %. How could I create a program that simulates turns from each team that continues until a player scores 15 times?

Comment: You shouldn't just ask for people to do things for you, make a base for your project and if you have an error, conduct thorough research and if nothing pops up then you can ask.

Answer (score 0):

*recursion* would be one way to do it:

```
do_stuff <- function(payload, turn = 1, max_turns = 15){
    if(turn >= max_turns) return(payload)
    payload  <- recalculate_payload(payload) ## desired recalculations here
    turn = turn + 1
    do_stuff(payload, turn, max_turns)
}

do_stuff(payload = pi) ## instead of Pi, could be a `data.frame` or other
```